# uniqueness of system of PDE using Lax Milgram

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, elliptic-equations

Consider the following question.

> (5) Consider the system
>
> (1)
>
> $$
> \begin{array}
> -\Delta u(x)-v(x)&=&f(x) && x \in \Omega \\
> u(x)-\Delta v(x) & = & g(x) && x \in \Omega \\
> u(x) & = & 0 && x \in \partial \Omega \\
> v(x) & = & 0 && x \in \partial \Omega
> \end{array}
> $$
> where $\Omega$ is a smooth, bounded domain.
> (a) Derive a weak formulation of system (1), using suitable test functions for each equation. Define a bilinear form $B((u, v),(w, q))$ such that the weak formulation is equivalent to
>
> (2)
> $$
> B((u, v),(w, q))=(f, w)+(g, q)
> $$
> (b) What are the appropriate function spaces for $u$ and $v$ in Eq. (2)?
> (c) Use the Lax-Milgram Theorem to show that the Eq. (2) has a unique solution.

[transcribed from this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4SM8.png)

I know that $u,v\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ but not sure how to apply Lax Milgram here.  Finding the norm of $(u,v)$ just doesn't make sense to me. $B((u,v),(u,v))$ just isn't looking right either since I multiplied the first equation by $w$ and the second one by $q$ and each equation has an expression involving both a function of $u$ and $v$.

How would Lax Milgram be applied in this problem? What does continuity and coercivity look like

Comment: First define the norm for the space $H:=H^1_0\times H^1_0$. Then it is the same as for one equation. Continuity should read for all $(w,q)\in H$: $\lvert B((u,v),(w,q)) \rvert \leq C\lVert (u,v) \rVert_H \lVert (w,q) \rVert_H$ and coercivity that there is $\alpha>0$ such that $\forall (u,v)\in H$, $B((u,v),(u,v))\geq \alpha\lVert (u,v) \rVert_H^2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creation of the weak formulation is a standard exercise. We assume $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$.

Indeed, suppose that $$
\Delta u(x) - v(x) = f(x) \quad ,\quad \forall \ x \in \Omega \tag{1}
$$

Let $\phi$ be a function in $\Omega$ whose regularity will be decided based on desired manipulations. Then, assuming that $(1)$ holds, we multiply by $\phi$  (note : while writing integrals, I omit the variable $x$ and the notation $dx$ to focus on the integrand. This is common practice in PDE):
$$
\phi\Delta u - \phi v = \phi f \implies \int_{\Omega} \phi \Delta u - \int_{\Omega} \phi v
 = \int_{\Omega} \phi f$$

Let's deal with just the first term : $\int_{\Omega} \phi \Delta u$, the rest will remain as they are. We write by extension by zero (allow $\phi$ to be zero on $\partial \Omega$, so the function remains integrable) :
$$
\int_{\Omega} \phi \Delta u = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \phi \Delta u 
$$

Under suitable conditions, Fubini's theorem  and integration-by-parts apply and we can write :
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^n} \phi \Delta u  = \int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \left[\int_{\mathbb R} \phi \Delta u \right] = -\int_{\mathbb R^{n-1}} \int_{\mathbb R} \nabla \phi \nabla u = -\int_{\mathbb R^n} \nabla \phi \nabla u = -\int_{\Omega} \nabla \phi \nabla u
$$

where the second equality follows from integration-by-parts and the fact that $\phi$ is compactly supported hence the derivatives of it vanish at infinity.

Which means we land up with the weak formulation for this particular equation :
$$
-\int_{\Omega} \nabla \phi \nabla u - \int_{\Omega} \phi v = \int_{\Omega} \phi f
$$

The conditions are quite self-evident : we require (weakly) $\nabla u , \nabla \phi$ to exist and be integrable , and furthermore vanish on the boundary. It is only natural to then call for $\phi,u \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.

The other equation is solved similarly, and results in
$$
\int_{\Omega} \nabla \phi \nabla v + \int_{\Omega} \phi u = \int_{\Omega} \phi g
$$

for all $\phi \in H_0^1(\Omega)$. Note that $v \in H_0^1(\Omega)$ from here as well.

---

To create our bilinear form is now extremely clear : we must "group" the two equations together. Define :
$$
B((\phi,\phi'),(u,v)) = \int_{\Omega} -\nabla \phi \nabla u - \int_{\Omega} \phi v + \int_{\Omega} \nabla \phi' \nabla v + \int_{\Omega} \phi' u
$$

so $B$ is a bilinear form on $H_0^1(\Omega) \times H_0^1(\Omega)$. Define :
$$
J : H_0^1(\Omega) \times H_0^1(\Omega) \to \mathbb R \quad ; \quad J(\phi,\phi') = \int_{\Omega} \phi f + \int_{\Omega} \phi' g
$$

this is a well defined linear functional. Our equation then becomes : find $(u,v)$ such that $$
B((\phi,\phi'),(u,v)) = J(\phi,\phi')
$$

for all $(\phi,\phi') \in H_0^1(\Omega)\times H_0^1(\Omega)$. We are firmly in Lax-Milgram territory ; the LHS is a bilinear form in $H_0^1(\Omega) \times H_0^1(\Omega)$ and the RHS is a linear functional on the same space.

---

To apply the Lax-Milgram theorem, whose direct consequence is the existence and uniqueness of $u,v$ satisfying the required equation (as desired), we must prove that $B$ is continuous and coercive, and $J$ is continuous.

Continuity of either one is fairly obvious :
$$
|B((\phi,\phi'),(u,v))| = \left|\int_{\Omega} -\nabla \phi \nabla u - \int_{\Omega} \phi v + \int_{\Omega} \nabla \phi' \nabla v + \int_{\Omega} \phi' u \right| \\
\leq \int_{\Omega} |\nabla \phi| |\nabla u| + \int_{\Omega} |\phi| |v| + \int_{\Omega} |\nabla \phi'| |\nabla v| + \int_{\Omega} |\phi'||u| \\
\leq \|\phi\|\|u\| + \|\phi\|\|v\| + \|\phi'\|\|u\| + \|\phi'\|\|v\| \\
\leq (\|(\phi,\phi')\|_{H_0^1 \times H_0^1}) (\|(u,v)\|_{H_0^1 \times H_0^1})
$$

where on the third line all norms are in $H_0^1$. I leave you to figure out the case for $J$.

The coercivity of $B$ follows from *Poincare's inequality*. Indeed, by Poincare's inequality, which can be used since $\Omega$ is bounded, we know that there exists a positive constant $C>0$ such that $\int_{\Omega} \nabla h  \nabla h \geq C \|h\|^2_{H_0^1}$ for every $h \in H_0^1(\Omega)$.

This helps massively, since :
$$
B((u,v),(u,v)) = \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla u + \int_{\Omega} v \cdot v + \int_{\Omega} \nabla v \nabla v + \int_{\Omega} u \cdot u \geq C(\|u\|_{H_0^1} + \|v\|_{H_0^1}) = C (\|(u,v)\|_{H_0^1 \times H_0^1})
$$

because the terms $u \cdot u , v \cdot v$ are non-negative, and for the rest the Poincare inequality apply (note : I'm putting the dots to indicate that it is a dot product : it was one earlier as well between the $\phi$s and $u,v$ but because they were different variables I did not use the dot)

Thus , we may use Lax-Milgram and complete the problem.